# CGZIPLibrary.dll not compressing files

Tags: vb.net, dll, vb6

HI, I am using CGZipLibrary.dll in my code for zipping the files. A .zip file is being created but the file is not getting compressed. The original file and the .zip file are of same size.

Please provide some suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you try to compress a file that is already compressed, it won't get any smaller.  Is it possible that this is case with your file?

Comment: Yeah, G Mastros is right. Examples of this are JPEGs, PNGs, MP3s, videos, etc, etc.

Comment: No i am not compressing an already compressed file. This is a csv file And moreover this is intermittent. works fine one day and fails other day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CGZipLibrary.dll... that's a rather old library if my memory is serving me right, I remember using it (or some other library with a similary name) in some old VB6 projects, and I had to update it because it had some problems when compressing folder structures. I may have the updated library lying somewhere around.

For .Net there are better alternatives like SharpZipLib and DotNetZip. I see the question is tagged with VB6 as well... if you need to use the library from VB6, from what I know, DotNetZip is marked as visible for COM, so you should be able to use it as well, although haven't tried it myself.

Comment: i am using it from vb.net .... My application was working fine for a long time and suddenly it started giving these compression problems. And moreover this is intermittent. works fine one day and fails other day.

Comment: If it's VB.Net, then go with either SharpZipLib or DotNetZip.